# Gmail.js to identify if Inbox or Promotions tab is selected

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

[image]

How do you know which tab is selected in Gmail via javascript? Or more specifically which tab a message is associate with. I am using the "[Gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js)" library, and only want to display an injected button when contextually relevant to the end user.